# fluttermaps depends on search_map_place ^0.3.0, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, google-maps, fluttermap

I am trying to add Google Maps in Flutter but, I am getting this kind of error so, can you guys help me solve it.

```
Because search_map_place >=0.3.0 depends on http ^0.12.0+4 and fluttermaps depends on http ^0.13.5, search_map_place >=0.3.0 is forbidden.
So, because fluttermaps depends on search_map_place 0.3.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because fluttermaps depends on search_map_place 0.3.0, version solving failed.)
```

Comment: you can upgrade http package to  latest one : 0.13.5

Comment: I already did but, the same error occur.

Comment: use `search_map_place_updated: ^0.0.4` instead of  `search_map_place`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the version numbers in pubspec.yaml

just put it like

```
search_map_place:
http:
```

and run pub get